# add class to first item in ng-repeat with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am new to complex directives and am trying to add a class to the first item in an ng-repeat with jquery (unfortunately my project is using it) like so inside a directive's controller:

```
   var highlightFirst = function(){
      $('.pointer').find('.fa-angle-down-first').next().addClass('boldit');
      console.log('in here')
    }

    highlightFirst();

    //also tried this:
    angular.element(document).ready(function(){
      $('.pointer').find('.fa-angle-down-first').next().addClass('boldit');
      console.log('in here')
    });
```

I invoke the function right after. nothing happens.

when I run `$('.pointer').find('.fa-angle-down-first').next().addClass('boldit');` 
in chrome dev tools, what I want to be bolded is in fact bolded...what am I missing to get this specific solution working? and what is the best angular way to do this?

Comment: Try using  this :  var highlightFirst = (function(){
              $('.pointer').find('.fa-angle-down-first').next().addClass('boldit');
              console.log('in here')
            });

Comment: That's my original code if I'm not mistaken?

Comment: Also I need more code to see if you had called the function correctly

Comment: No its not the same it has extra pranteses and ; a the end

Comment: can't see why i'd need the extra parenthesis. I have updated to include more code

Comment: Why aren't you just using ng-class to check if the element you're repeating is the first?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You don't actually need jquery for it and should avoid using jquery as much as possible in angular applications, you should use `ng-class` and [$first](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) here's the working [demo](http://jsbin.com/soyeyuxina/2/edit?html,css,js,output)

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="{'fooClass': $first}">{{ item }}</li>
</ul>
```

The good thing about `$first` is when you sort the `ng-repeat` it would still work correctly.

Comment: Sure angular way is preferred but I don't know it. So I will give +1 if you have tested that your code is working

Comment: That's cool but I needed to access the first item in the first item in a nested ng repeat so the above solution with $first was better suited to my needs

Comment: It will still work in nested ng-repeat, I'll create a fiddle

Comment: @imsiso I created a working demo :)

devdropper87, I demonstrated the nested ng-repeat with the first item with a specific class, please see the demo.

Comment: OK so I will try it. Thanks and +1

Comment: This is actually better than the accepted solution. @ncm is using an Angular `ng-repeat`, so knowledge of `$first` should be something to obtain post-haste. This also allows for sorting and paging, and won't get ganked by anything like selecting the first item in items by index.

Solid answer, @LouieAlmeda.

Answer (score 13):

Just use ng-class:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="{'myClass': item == items[0]}">{{ item.property }}</li>
</ul>
```

Edit: link to more details

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Comment: @devdropper87 this will break if you start sorting and filtering the items inside the ng-repeat

Answer (score 2):

Let's try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.pointer').find('.fa-angle-down-first').next().addClass('boldit');
  console.log('in here');
});
```

And about your first way:

```
var highlightFirst = function(){
  $('.pointer').find('.fa-angle-down-first').next().addClass('boldit');
  console.log('in here');
};

highlightFirst();
```

I should say you should make sure your code is being run after page and elements have been loaded.

Comment: This is highly dependend on jquery, which will soon break angular's two way binding

Comment: So you don't like my answer? Or you mean its good? Sorry my English is not good

Comment: Angular applications should NOT be highly dependent on jquery :)

Comment: Yes I agree. But its still useful cause it contains other information.

Comment: I understand, as I came from jquery world before I used angular. AngularJS wants to separate your data and view, There will always be ways to avoid using jquery, and you'll love it when you get used to it :)